# Windows Media Player SDK: обработать | предотвратить OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, исключения, memory

```
WindowsMediaPlayer WMP = new WindowsMediaPlayer(); //Создаётся WMP
IWMPMediaCollection collection = WMP.mediaCollection; //"Создаётся" коллекция муз. библиотеки WMP
IWMPMedia newMedia = collection.add(path);  //А вот здесь, после 5 тысяч повторений, возникает исключение
```

Пробовала поймать для принудительной сборки мусора в отдельном методе – не помогло, память по-прежнему переполняется.

Интересны любые соображения и опыт тех, кто работал с этими интерфейсами.

Comment: Вам не кажется, что 5К медиа-объектов в памяти это перебор? Зачем вам столько *сразу*?

Comment: Да, это, действительно, многовато. Но их в медиабиблиотеке может быть в тот момент больше. Вопрос, собственно, и состоит в том, как освободить память.